# How to delete a child value of a specific user in Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, key

[I want to delete the value "chocolate" under a specific userid, how can I do it?
I dont know how to retrieve the key "-LPff5K_qPj7heMWiNfZ:". Say I am having a string chocolate now, how can I search this word in firebase and delete it? PLEASE HELP. Thank you!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC2ha.png)

Answer (score 0):

I will do like this :

Change every user - child with simple keyword easy to find - I usually use the TOKEN given by google and it still the same every time that the user sign-in.
Change every token - child with easy variables like Hobby, name , surname ecc.
It will be easy for you search every user and specific child.
Let me go home and i'll post some code :D